# MySQL Homebrew Warning: m4 macros were installed to "share/aclocal"

Tags: mysql

Received this warning when installing MySQL:

```
Warning: m4 macros were installed to "share/aclocal".
Homebrew does not append "/usr/local/share/aclocal"
to "/usr/share/aclocal/dirlist". If an autoconf script you use
requires these m4 macros, you'll need to add this path manually.
```

Managed to start MySQL in safe mode using:

```
# cd . ; ./bin/mysqld_safe &
```

However, I can't start the server normally by trying:

```
# mysql.server start
Starting MySQL
. ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql/robell.local.pid).
```

Also noticed that this file doesn't exist:

```
# launchctl load -w /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.5.19/com.mysql.mysqld.plist
launchctl: Couldn't stat("/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.5.19/com.mysql.mysqld.plist"): No such file or directory
nothing found to load
```

Answer (score 0):

```
brew info mysql
```

will list a few steps that are required prior to starting the server, due to the subtleties of permissions and how Homebrew never uses sudo.  Good luck.